# HTTP to HTTPS redirection in htaccess does not work for some URLs

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, http-status-code-404, http-redirect

In my Wordpress site (example.com, which has its default htaccess file) I have set the htaccess to redirect all its paths to https using the following directive.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However all paths works including the attempts to load the site with http://example.com/ but some paths for example http://example.com/contact-us/ generates a 404 but works perfectly with https://example.com/contact-us/.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess? Are there more than .htaccess in your system?

Comment: @anubhava No, Only one .htaccess file and it's a wordpress site with its default htaccess rules.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue...